# Pointwise convergence of a sectionally defined function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, sequence-of-function

I'm asking for a proof-verification of the following:

$ 
     f_n(x) := \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 2n^2x, & x\in [0,\frac{1}{2n}) \\
         -2n^2x+2n, & x\in [\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n})\\ 0,& x \in [\frac{1}{n},1]\end{array}\right. . $

Claim: $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ where $f(x):= 0$.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon_1 := 2(n+1)^2x \,\, and \,\, x \in [0,1]$

$\Rightarrow \mid f_n(x) - f(x) \mid = \mid f_n(x) - 0\mid = \mid f_n(x) \mid$

Case one: $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2n})$

$\mid 2n^2x \mid = 2n^2x < \epsilon_1 \forall n$

Case two: $x \in [\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n})$ Let $\epsilon_2 > 0,$ $\epsilon_2 := 2(n+1)^2x+2(n+1)$

$\mid -2n^2x+2n\mid \leq \mid -2n^2x \mid + \mid 2n \mid = 2n^2x +2n < \epsilon_2 \forall n$

Case three: $ x \in [\frac{1}{n},1]$ Let $ \epsilon_3 > 0, \epsilon_3 := 1$

$\mid 0 \mid = 0 < \epsilon_3 \forall n$

$\Rightarrow f_n$ converges to $f$ when $n \rightarrow \infty $ where $f(x) := 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your $\varepsilon$'s depend upon $n$ and $x$, your proof is wrong. There can be no restriction on the value of $\varepsilon$, apart from the fact that we must have $\varepsilon>0$.

There are two cases to be considered:

- $x=0$. Then each $f_n(0)$ is equal to $0$ and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(0)=0$.
- $x\in(0,1]$: then take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1N\leqslant x$. Then $n\geqslant N\implies f_n(x)=0$. Therefore, again, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$.

EDIT:

Read comments for further information

Comment: Alright but I don't really get how to construct a strict $\epsilon$ - proof then

Comment: That's what I did, right?! Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then each $f_n(0)$ is equal to $0$ and therefore $\bigl\lvert f_n(0)-0\bigr\rvert=0<\varepsilon$, for each $n$. And, if $x>0$, you take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1N<x$ and then $f_n(x)=0$. Therefore, again, we have $\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-0\bigr\rvert=0<\varepsilon$, this time for each $n\geqslant N$.

Comment: "And, if >0, you take ∈ℕ such that 1< and then ()=0. Therefore, again, we have ∣∣()−0∣∣=0<, this time for each ⩾." That's the part I don't understand especially this $ N \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{1}{N} < x \Rightarrow f_n(x) = 0$

Comment: Do you agree that, if $x>0$, then there is a natural $N$ such that $\frac1N<x$?

Comment: Yes I understand that but I don't how you follow this $f_n(x) = 0$

Comment: Well, if $n\geqslant N$, you also have $\frac1n<x$. Now, take a look at the definition of $f_n$:$$x>\frac1n\implies f_n(x)=0.$$

Comment: OMG, thank you! I missed the last part of the sectionwise definition of $f_n$. I should read more carefully

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.